# bash: Something like quotemeta() for pattern characters?

Tags: bash, escaping

## Background

I am aware of bash's various [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) capabilities.

Also, I know I can escape special pattern characters with a backslash `\`.

For instance:

```
# x is a literal string 'foo*bar'
x="foo*bar"

# prints "*bar".
echo "${x##foo}"

# prints nothing, since the '*' is interpreted as a glob.
echo "${x##foo*}"

# prints "bar", since I escaped the '*'.
echo "${x##foo\*}"
```

## The Problem

The above is all fine and dandy.
The problem is when the pattern comes in from somewhere else, and it may not have the `*` and other special globbing characters escaped.

For example:

```
prefix="foo*"

... later, in some faraway code ...

x="foo*bar"
# I want this to print 'bar'. So I want the '*' to be escaped. But how?
echo "${x##$prefix}"
```

Essentially, I'm looking for something analogous to Perl's [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) function.

Is there something like this in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I figured this out just after posting.

The answer (as always) is: add more quotes (:

For my example:

```
prefix="foo*"

... later, in some faraway code ...

x="foo*bar"

# Prints 'bar' since the pattern has double-quotes surrounding it.
echo "${x##"$prefix"}"
```